# In bash, how do I determine if only one of a set of variable has a value?

Tags: bash

I have three variables, let's call them `DATE`, `URI` and `URI_FILE`. They contain the results of processing the command line with `getopt`:

```
while getopts ":d:p:u:hFA" opt; do

   case $opt in
       d) DATE=$OPTARG;;
       u) URI=${OPTARG};;
       U) URI_FILE=${OPTARG};;
       F) FORCE=yes;;
       A) ALL=yes;;

   esac

done
```

I need to fail with an error if more than one of those variables are set to any value (they are alternative command line options). I'm completely clueless about how to test that elegantly. I have something that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ -z "${URI+x}" ]]
then
    URI_PRESENT=0
else
    URI_PRESENT=1
fi

if [[ -z "${URI_FILE+x}" ]]
then
    URI_FILE_PRESENT=0
else
    URI_FILE_PRESENT=1
fi

if [[ -z "${DATE+x}" ]]
then
    DATE_PRESENT=0
else
    DATE_PRESENT=1
fi


ARGCOUNT=$((${DATE_PRESENT} + ${URI_FILE_PRESENT} + ${URI_PRESENT}))

if (( ${ARGCOUNT} > 1 ))
then
    echo "Only one of date, uri and uri-file may be supplied"
    exit 1
fi
```

There has to be a cleaner way to do this. Suggestions? I'm going to be adding at least on more alternative and this will get painful

Comment: Well, you could of course set the flags for "present" and total count in the `case` where you process the commands, you can have more than one command before the `;;`.  You could even test while in that `case` block if something has already been set (with a flag) and bail out at that moment.

Comment: What's the desired behavior if someone specifies the same argument-value twice (e.g `... -d x -d y ...`  - fail or accept the first value or accept the last value or something else? Don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names by the way - by convention and to avoid clashing with exported variable names.

Comment: When you have an error when any other option is given, you can break the second time you are in the loop.

Comment: @EdMorton Accept last value would work just fine. And upper-case - good point.

Comment: @NicGibson that is the normal behavior from most tools so I agree that's the right approach but that's not what [the solution you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54831331/1745001) will do, it'll fail with an incorrect/misleading error message as it can't distinguish multiple occurrences of one option from single occurrences of multiple options.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point - and my code (which I ended up writing based on a comment) will do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an associative array indexed by each of the mutually exclusive options present in the options list and then report if it's size is greater than 1:

```
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A opts
while getopts ":d:u:U:hFA" opt; do
    case $opt in
    d) DATE=$OPTARG
       opts["$opt"]=1;;
    u) URI=${OPTARG}
       opts["$opt"]=1;;
    U) URI_FILE=${OPTARG}
       opts["$opt"]=1;;
    F) FORCE=yes;;
    A) ALL=yes;;
    esac
    if (( ${#opts[@]} > 1 )); then
        echo "Only one of date, uri or uri-file may be supplied" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

That will allow multiple instances of the same option to be present on the command line while disallowing instances of 2 or more different options.

Comment: @EdNorton - that's a much better approach than the one I accepted. Apologies!

Answer (score 3):

From [mickp's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830622/in-bash-how-do-i-determine-if-only-one-of-a-set-of-variable-has-a-value#comment96436239_54830622):

> Why not have a single flag which gets incremented in every `case` expression and then test if it's greater than 1?

Implemented:

```sh
while getopts ":d:p:u:hFA" opt; do
   case $opt in
   d) DATE=$OPTARG
      ((count++));;
   u) URI=${OPTARG}
      ((count++));;
   U) URI_FILE=${OPTARG}
      ((count++));;
   F) FORCE=yes;;
   A) ALL=yes;;
   esac
   if ((count > 1)); then
       echo "Only one of date, uri or uri-file may be supplied" >&2
       exit 1
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty well exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
counter=0
[[ $DATE ]] && ((counter+=1))
[[ $URI ]] && ((counter+=1))
[[ $URI_FILE ]] && ((counter+=1))

if ((counter > 1))
then
    echo "Only one of date, uri and uri-file may be supplied" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```